# Concatenar string e retornar o número de caracteres

Tags: javascript, string, soma

Preciso fazer o seguinte:

1 - Criar uma função chamada `tamanhoNomeCompleto`
2 - Que recebi nome e sobrenome como parâmetro, ou seja, dois parâmetros 
3 - Essa função irá devolver o tamanho total, contando um espaço extra para separar ambos
4 - Estou usando o `length` (comprimento) para contar as letras e espaços
5 - Estou passando como parâmetro a *string* 'Juan Perez' <= note que tem um espaço entre os nomes
6 - Preciso que a execução da função `tamanhoNomeCompleto` me retorne 10 <= número de caracteres e espaço em 'Juan Perez'

Eu fiz da maneira a seguir, porém meu resultado é NaN. O que será que está errado?

```
function tamanhoNomeCompleto(nome,sobrenome) {
    return ('Juan'.lenght+' '.lenght+'Perez'.lenght);
}
tamanhoNomeCompleto('Juan','Perez');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem alguns erros aí.

O mais óbvio é que cometeu um erro de digitação no nome da propriedade que dá o tamanho do texto, o correto é `length`. JavaScript em vez de dar erro e encerrar, tenta fazer a conta assim mesmo, então dá um resultado maluco.

Mas na verdade a função nem faz sentido, é para você fazer a conta do tamanho dos dados de acordo com os parâmetros recebidos e não com literais. Além disso não precisa pegar o tamanho de 1 espaço porque o resultado sempre será 1 então pode somar isso de forma direta, não é que não funcione, mas não faz sentido, vai se acostumando fazer um código mais simples e, rápido, e até legível.

```js
function tamanhoNomeCompleto(nome,sobrenome) {
    return nome.length + sobrenome.length + 1;
}
console.log(tamanhoNomeCompleto('Juan', 'Perez'));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/CountChars.js).

Comment: Questão resolvida. Entendi sua lógica. Obrigado Mineiro !

Answer (score 0):

Existem alguns erros em sua função:

- Você utilizou a propriedade `length` com a escrita incorreta, estava
  escrito *lenght*, corrigindo isso sua função já vai funcionar.
- Você recebeu os parâmetros mas não utilizou eles na função, você fixou os nomes dentro da função, com isso ela só funcionara para o nome *Juan Perez*.

---

Veja abaixo a sua função com as devidas correções:

```js
function tamanhoNomeCompleto(nome,sobrenome) {
    return nome.length + ' '.length + sobrenome.length;
}

const tamanhoJuan = tamanhoNomeCompleto('Juan', 'Perez');

console.log( tamanhoJuan );

const tamanhoMarcelo = tamanhoNomeCompleto('Marcelo', 'Maciel');

console.log( tamanhoMarcelo );
```

A propriedade `length` foi corrigida, com isso não será mais retornando `NaN` na soma dos tamanhos, além disso agora os parâmetros `nome` e `sobrenome` estão sendo utilizados na função, tornando-a dinâmica, podendo trabalhar com diversos nomes.

***Obs.:** Como o tamanho de um espaço sempre será `1`, você poderia remover o `length` do espaço e somar `+1` no final, também funcionará.*

---

> Documentações:
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions